# phpmyadmin won't change MySQL TINYINT(1) to BOOLEAN data type

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm running MySQL 5.5.47 and have a number of database tables that have columns with a data type of `TINYINT(1)`. I'm attempting to change these to `BOOLEAN` but it won't change them.

Using phpmyadmin 4.6.0 then going to Structure I'm using the dropdown to set the columns to `BOOLEAN`. This executes the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE `feedback` CHANGE `tick_receive_updates` `tick_receive_updates` BOOLEAN NOT NULL;
```

The query runs successfully.

When I view the Structure it does not update: the columns are still marked as being `TINYINT(1)`

At first I thought this was a phpmyadmin bug so I ran

```
DESCRIBE feedback;
```

Unfortunately the problem remains - columns have not changed from `TINYINT(1)`

Why is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is normal behavior as `BOOLEAN` is just a **synonym** of `TINYINT(1)`

[MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual - 12.1.1 Numeric Type Overview](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

> **BOOL, BOOLEAN**
>
> These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered
>   false. Nonzero values are considered true:

Comment: Interesting. I wonder then why they're providing BOOLEAN as an option at all then? I'll accept this as a solution since when I create a *new* table (rather than modifying an existing one) and set it to BOOLEAN it does indeed show as TINYINT(1) when using DESCRIBE or looking at the Structure tab. Very odd!

Comment: it's not an option, it's a synonym. There are multiple synonyms in MySQL and there are multiple reasons for them. BOOLEAN being a real data type on other RDBMS, a synonym makes transitions easier for a developer. Ther's no real other explanation for this one.